# Jmeter: Extract one field array from object array json respone

Tags: json, http, jmeter, extract

I have following response:

```
{
  "total" : 643,
  "strikes" : [ {
    "putOptionId" : 110,
    ....
  }, {
    "putOptionId" : 114,
    ....
  }]
}
```

I want to extract all `putOptionId` to array.

I use json path extractor for this aim:
[image]

but in debug sampler I see following result:

```
optionIds=
```

What do I wrong?

Does this extractor applicable?

Answer (score 0):

Following expression works

```
$.strikes[*].putOptionId
```